# How to get the SharePoint Group Name based on PrincipalID

Tags: groups, ssom, spaudit, spauditeventtype

I am trying to get the name of SharePoint group based on `PrincipalID`, But finding no luck with below code.

Can anyone help me in getting with below concern.

```
XmlDocument xmlEventData = new XmlDocument();
xmlEventData.LoadXml(string.Format("<EventData>{0}</EventData>", en.EventData));

var principalId = xmlEventData.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/EventData/principalId").InnerText;
if(principalId!=null)
{
    var group = web.Groups.GetByID((int.Parse(principalId)));
}

string operation = xmlEventData.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/EventData/operation").InnerText;
```